# Keep window on top of taskbar on Windows 11

Tags: winapi

I found that on windows 11, even if I created windows with `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style, the window still get covered by taskbar if you click anywhere on the taskbar. The **only exception** to  this is task manager. How does it achieve it?

I want a feature to draw stuff on the taskbar, or at least mimic that behavior using a transparent window. I think there used to be 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Get DC of taskbar and draw (which no longer work on Windows11)
2. Create a transparent window and keep it on top of taskbar (issues with how to keep it topmost)

I kind of get stuck now. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
I just noticed that the taskbar window, shown as `DesktopWindowXamlSource` in *Spy++* does not have the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style set. I guess it's possible to cover it for some ways?

```cpp
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,                  // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And this is how the window get covered by taskbar when I click start.
[image]

Comment: "How does it achieve it?" It is part of the system, your code is not.

Comment: MS reasonably doesn't really want you to do this... because malware authors could use it to block access to things.

Comment: Possibly some [DWM window attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute), maybe an undocumented one.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? What do you mean keep window on top of taskbar? Whether you want the window to cover the taskbar?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT added

Comment: "The only exception to this is task manager. How does it achieve it?" The task manager window is not covered by the taskbar.Task Manager window is not the exception.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I wrote normal windows with topmost style would get covered, and task manager won't get covered. So it is the exception. Actually I found more exceptions that won't get covered. Those were the system components so I guess David was right.